# Changing the color of selected tab

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I am using `tabLayout` to use tabs in my app. I want to change the background color & text color of selected tab. I am changing the background color of entire `tabLayout` by doing this

```
 android:background="@color/colorAccent"
```

and changing textcolor and selectedtextcolor

```
app:tabTextColor="#000000"
app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
```

but all i want to do now is to change the background color of that specific tab when it is selected ? How to do that ?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: please don't ask duplicate questions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can do it like this in your tab layout widget

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout

    app:tabBackground="@drawable/selector"

    />
```

and define your selector.xml in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
     android:drawable="@color/tab_selected_color" 
     android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item 
     android:drawable="@color/tab_unselected_color"
     android:state_selected="false"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Worked perfect...Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

> Change the background colour of tab in TabLayout is fairly simple
>   using the design support library that Android provides. You can simply
>   change the background of the whole TabLayout using the
>   app:tabBackground property and you can change the tab indicator colour
>   using the app:tabIndicatorColor property, but there are better ways if
>   you want more functionality. A better way to change the tab-layout
>   colour is using selectors, using selectors you can have different
>   background for different sates of tab i.e selected, unselected etc.

*Please follow the below steps:*

**1. Create a drawable, tab_selected_background, that will be use as the background for the selected tab**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
</shape>
```

**2. Create a selector, tab_selector that will be used as the background for tab layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_background" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/tab_background_unselected"/>
</selector>
```

**3. Now finally create the tab layout and use the selector that we've just create as the background of the tabLayout.**

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/subChordTabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/tabIndicator"
        android:padding="8dp"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"/>
```

You gotta the result like below,

[image]